# Error on ternary operation when using Twig

Tags: php, twig

i want to use my twig for the condition if the **route** is blank then it will use **home.color_scheme** else it will use **setting.color_scheme**. Here's my code:

```
{% if home.color_scheme != 'default' or setting.color_scheme != 'default'  %}
    <link href="/css/color-variations/{% route == '' ? home.color_scheme : setting.color_scheme  %}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
{% endif %}
```

but it makes some error like this:

```
 'Unexpected "route" tag (expecting closing tag for the "if" tag defined near line 17).'
```

so what makes this error and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link href="/css/color-variations/{{ route == '' ? home.color_scheme : setting.color_scheme  }}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

you suppose to use {{ instead of {%.

Comment: it work, but i see no output. it suppose have an output like yellow.css or red.css why i just see it ".css" only?

Comment: ah ok, i found the problem already, i direct it on the wrong controller. thanks.